# Subquery Count in Python Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, subquery

I have a problem with subquery count in Python Django...

Query MySQL:

```
SELECT usuario.name, COUNT(*) AS Groups,(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM group
    WHERE group.user_id=user.id and state = 'on going') AS Started
FROM user
INNER JOIN group
ON (user.id=group.user_id)
WHERE user.rol = 'Provider'
GROUP BY group.user_id
ORDER BY Groups desc;
```

Views:

```
connected_query= GroupModel.objects.values(
'usuario__name').filter(
user__rol='PROVIDER'.lower(), status='ON_GOING'.lower()).annotate(
started=Count('user'))


totals_query = GroupModel.objects.values(
provider=Concat('user__name', Value(' '), 'user__surname')).annotate(
totals=Count('user'),connected=Subquery(connected_query.values('started')[:1])).order_by(
'-connected')


First query return:
<QuerySet [{'user__name': 'James', 'started': 3}, {'user__name': 'John', 'started': 2}, {'user__name': 'Frank', 'started': 2}, {'user__name': 'Sara', 'started': 1}]>

While second query return:
<QuerySet [{'user__name': 'James', 'totals': 10, 'started': 3}, {'user__name': 'John', 'totals': 10, 'started': 3}, {'user__name': 'Frank', 'totals': 12, 'started': 3}, {'user__name': 'Sara', 'totals': 9, 'started': 3}]>
```

I need the query to return the following:

```
<QuerySet [{'user__name': 'James', 'totals': 10, 'started': 3}, {'user__name': 'John', 'totals': 10, 'started': 2}, {'user__name': 'Frank', 'totals': 12, 'started': 2}, {'user__name': 'Sara', 'totals': 9, 'started': 1}]>
```

The problem is that the second query, always return 3, which are the connected that the user 'James', if in subquery I remove [:1] python gives me the following error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')

I don't know where to continue, I'm a bit desperate, any help is good

Comment: group is a reserved word..

Comment: I know, it really is a grupo (in Spanish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may update your query to -

```
SELECT usuario.name, COUNT(*) AS Groups, COUNT(state = 'on going') AS Started
FROM user
INNER JOIN group
ON (user.id=group.user_id)
WHERE user.rol = 'Provider'
GROUP BY group.user_id
ORDER BY Groups desc;
```

Comment: With that query I get this: 

`<QuerySet [{'user__name': 'James', 'ge_totals': 10, 'started': 10}, {'user__name': 'John', 'ge_totals': 10, 'started': 10}, {'user__name': 'Frank', 'ge_totals': 12, 'started': 12}, {'user__name': 'Sara', 'ge_totals': 9, 'started': 9}]>`

Comment: Does everyone have state as 'on going'?

Comment: Yes, all users, have at least 1 state as 'on going'

Comment: Thanks for your query, it gave me a hint, I did not know that you could give parameters to count, my ny query is: 
`SELECT us.name, COUNT(gr.Id) , COUNT(case when status='on going' then 1 END)
FROM user us
INNER JOIN group gr
ON (us.id = gr.User_id) 
WHERE us.Rol = "Provider"
GROUP BY gr.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

It's already solved, much easier than using a subquery, I have used Case, the new MySQL query:

```
SELECT us.name, COUNT(gr.Id) , COUNT(case when status='on going' then 1 END)
FROM user us
INNER JOIN group gr
ON (us.id = gr.User_id) 
WHERE us.Rol = "Provider"
GROUP BY gr.user_id
```

Views:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Value, Case, When
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

totals_query = GrupoModel.objects.values(
provider=Concat('usuario__nombre', Value(' '), 'usuario__apellidos')).annotate(
totals=Count('user'),connected=Count(Case(When(status='ON_GOING'.lower(),then=1)))).order_by(
'-connected')
```